# Unique django admin site for every different user

Tags: django, django-admin

Is it possible for the seperate users to see the unique changes they made to django admin?
For example if user1 has added some products or categories to be able to see his unique changes - admin site?
If it's not how could i construct such a feature using the django admin as a base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following link:

[Users and the admin](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/dec/24/admin/)

Answer (score 0):

Django is great framework and there is [LogEntry model](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/models.py#L18) 
You have to register this model in admin

**Something like this**

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()
admin.site.register(admin.model.LogEntry)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

**Or extended example:**

extra_admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

class LogEntryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)"
   pass

admin.site.register(admin.model.LogEntry, LogEntryAdmin)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

import extra_admin.py

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```